# Spring-integration gateway cannot be autowired, no qualifying bean found

Tags: spring-integration, spring-bean

I am trying to send the output from a spring batch process to RabbitMQ. To avoid hard dependency on Rabbitmq, I used spring-integration as suggested in [Is there an API in spring-xd to write to a message bus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226211/is-there-an-api-in-spring-xd-to-write-to-a-message-bus/28226732#28226732). I had everything working fine with messages being pushed to RabbitMQ, until I decided to autowire or instantiate the beans via Spring.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.*"/> 
<channel id="input" />

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" />

<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    exchange="testExchange" routing-key="foo.bar" />
<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />
<rabbit:queue name="testQueue" id="timeseriesQueue" />
<rabbit:topic-exchange name="testExchange"
    id="testExchange">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="testQueue" pattern="foo.*" />
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:topic-exchange>

<!-- Send message to rabbitmq -->
<gateway id="testGateway"
    service-interface="com.test.TestService"
    default-request-channel="input" />


<amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="input"
    amqp-template="amqpTemplate" exchange-name="testExchange"
    routing-key="foo.bar" />
```

The testService is just an interface with the method sendMessage.

The spring batch job has an itemWriter, which uses the gateway bean to write to RabbitMQ

In the write method of itemWriter, when I instantiated the bean using ApplicationContext, like below, it worked well

```
AbstractApplicationContext ctx =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring/integration/rabbit.xml");

     TestService service = ctx.getBean("testGateway", TestService.class);
    service.sendMessage(items);
    ctx.close();
```

However, when I tried to autowire it, like below:

```
@Autowired
TestService service;
```

I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.test.TestService com.test.TransportItemWriter.testGateway; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.test.TestService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.test.TestService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
... 24 more
```

I tried looking around, but most examples (in spring-integration samples) of Gateway invoke it via ApplicationContext. I found http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-integration-gateways-1, and added whatever annotation I thought I was missing, but could not get it working.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autowiring is functionally equivalent to getting the bean from the context (unless there's more than one instance, in which case, you need the right variable name, or a `@Qualifier`), but that would give you a different error. Is the gateway in the same context as the `ItemWriter`?

```
`META-INF/spring/integration/rabbit.xml`
```

implies it's in its own context. Are you `<import/>` ing in into your job context?

I usually debug issues like this by turning on debug logging for `org.springframework`; it emits copious logs for bean wiring.

Another good debug technique is to `@Autowire` the `ApplicationContext` and print out `ctx.getBeanFactory().toString()`.

Comment: I tried out your suggestion with turning on the debug. You were right. It didnt have the context. Itemwriter and rabbit were declared in different contexts, so just to try out, I moved the configs in rabbit.xml to the one in the writer. Worked like a charm. I probably just have to import these now. thanks again.

Answer (score 8):

I was dealing with similar issue recently. The solution was to add new annotation in config:

> @IntegrationComponentScan("path.to.your.gateway")

Comment: Bless you for saving me a lot of time. Now I learned something new. ^_^

Comment: i m using spring boot 2.2.2 with integration, no idea i got null pointer trying to inject the @MessagingGateway....

Answer (score 5):

It's a old question I know, but I had a Similar Issue:

I would use a anotated class `@MessagingGateway` interface called `MySFTPUploadGateway.java` (is a gateway of course) placed in mydependency1.jar. Also I have a SpringBoot app called ApplicationMain.jar, but when i start my application this crash because **ApplicationMain.jar**, on runtime, not found `MySFTPUploadGateway.class` for autowiring as a Bean.
I tried `@ComponentScan("<path_to_MySFTPUploadGateway.class_on_mydependency1>")`, also with `@EnableIntegration` but anything worked.

Reading a little about this, I Found https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2037, cool, **I think I have my solution with** `@IntegrationComponentScan` ( the clue that gave me @jogo).
But... This anotation only works with @EnableAutoConfiguration. This is the key.

**So put your:**

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@IntegrationComponentScan("<yourpathPackage>")
```

..and keep it running !

Comment: You made my day ;) After adding IntegrationComponentScan bean with MessageChannel was created